# Clarity on function WorkflowApplication.LoadRunnableInstance()

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

`WorkflowApplication..::.LoadRunnableInstance`

Can anyone use this in a sentence? (Im looking for an example usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking here. Do you want an example of how to use LoadRunnableInstance or do you want to know what LoadRunnableInstance does?

Assuming you want to know what it does, it will basically load a workflow instance from the instance store if there is an runnable instance in the store, ie. an instance that was delayed for example and the delay period has expired.

Typically you would query the instance store to check if there is an activatable instance available and if there is call LoadRunnableInstance to load the instance into memory and resume execution of the workflow, like [this example](http://adrianot75.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/wf4-persisnce-delay-and-execution-resume/).

Comment: hi chris, thats exactly what im looking for do you have any code samples, im really curious on how one would query the instancestore and reload wfs that should be reloaded

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have only just started with the WF 4.0 stuff my self.